# Arduino mega 2560 with Raspberry pie 2 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino, raspberry-pi2

I am currently working on a project where I need to control 16 pumps 1 stepper motor and 2 Distance sensors - 21 digital pins and 2 analog pins. I need to make a UI and have this use UI send information to the Arduino which will control my system. I would only need to receive 1 or 0 from each button press from the UI in order to determine which pump to needs to be turned on. I'm using an Arduino mega 2560 and coding the UI in Visual Studio C#.

I have done various research on serial communication for the Arduino, including using the `serialevent()` function and the firmata library. However I am having trouble understanding how all this ties together and if what I am wanting to do is even possible! Here are my questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. Is this possible by using `Serialevent1()`........... `serialevent21()`? or using `Serial.availble()` and `Serial.read()`
3. Instead of reading one button click on the UI at a time. Can the inputs on the UI be collected and sent to the arduino as a group. Then have the UI restart and clear out the values.

Any information and/or advice will help! I just need to be pointed in the correct direction!

Thanks
DG

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project, but unfortunately it's a very broad question that is unsuitable for Stack Overflow. I would advise asking smaller simpler questions, ideally based on your attempts (showing code)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473828/Arduino-Csharp-and-Serial-Interface)?
It uses a Arduino mega 2560 and the article provides both the c# code and the Arduino code. 
It communicates over the serial port and sends data in both directions.

1. Yes it is
2. The article above uses the Serial.print and readSerialInputCommand which is similar to Serial.read. You can use Serial.Read instead if you wish as it performs the same task and returns a different datatype.
3. You can compile the values into a group. If you want to be super optimized you can use bit-wise operators and compile the first 21 pin values into a byte array and send it. 
   However since its only 21 digital pins I recommend just using a string with the each character in the string linked to a pin. Eg: "10110" could set pin0, pin2, pin3 HIGH and set pin1, pin5 LOW.
   I would recommend not restarting your UI as it will need to reconnect to serial port. Rather just clear all the values with your code.

Comment: Thanks! I will certainly look into that. I will let you know how it goes